# How can I format below date using moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have `"2017-12-14T4:0:14-06:00"` this date value in mongodb I want to format it something like this:

```
moment(new Date("2017-12-14T4:0:14-06:00")).format('MMM DD,YYYY A')
```

Actually below Returns **Invalid date**.

```
new Date("2017-12-14T4:0:14-06:00");
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```js
const d = moment("2017-12-14T4:0:14-06:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ")
             .format('MMM DD,YYYY A');
console.log(d)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but don't know why for "2017-12-14T3:58:21-06:00" .
I am getting Dec 14,0017 PM. Means not 2017 but 0017 why?

Comment: Are you using `"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"` or this `"YYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ"`? The 2nd one has one less `Y` which results in 0017